# Efficient way to see if an IP address is in a list of subnets

Tags: postgresql, ipv6, ipv4

I basically have a 2 column table with an IP subnet as the key/index and a description as the value.  For example:

```
10.20.30.0/30  "Subnet 1"
```

I need to write a REST service that will return the description of the subnet containing the given IP address, or list of subnets if the IP address matches more than one.

At first, I thought I would simply use a backend database (Postgres) and expand all the subnets because I wasn't dealing with large amounts of data.  So the above example would be expanded to:

```
10.20.30.0  "Subnet 1"
10.20.30.1  "Subnet 1"
10.20.30.2  "Subnet 1"
10.20.30.3  "Subnet 1"
```

This is inefficient in terms of storage, especially as subnets get large.  However, it is quick and easy to do, and existing databases have really efficient ways to lookup IP addresses as indexes, so this was my first idea.  I am mostly concerned with lookup efficiency since I will have about 1 million entries in my DB.

However, I found out I also have requirements for IPv6, and the subnets involved are HUGE.  This means I no longer have the option of expanding all the subnets.

Before I go ahead and start writing my custom REST API I wanted to know if POSTGRES queries for checking IP addresses using subnets as an index are efficient.  The check is not trivial and I don't know how it would be done internally to maintain efficiency.

Does anyone know how POSTGRES checks for IP addresses in tables indexed by subnet?

**EDIT:** Here is an example of IP address lookup in POSTGRES that I am talking about (using online https://extendsclass.com/postgresql-online.html)

```
drop table ipdesc;
create table ipdesc (addr inet, category varchar(20));
insert into ipdesc (addr, category) values ('10.10.10.0/24', 'tens');
insert into ipdesc (addr, category) values ('20.20.20.0/24', 'twenties');
insert into ipdesc (addr, category) values ('50.50.50.0/24', 'fifties');
insert into ipdesc (addr, category) values ('50.50.50.0/30', 'sub-fifty');
select * from ipdesc where inet '50.50.50.1' << addr;
```

Results:

```
addr           category
----           --------
50.50.50.0/24  fifties
50.50.50.0/30  sub-fifty
```

Thanks!

Comment: With a network, not only do you need the address, but you need a mask or mask length to break the address into the network and host parts. Simply having an address like `10.20.30.0` does not tell you what the network is, you need something like what you have above that (`10.20.30.0/30`) that has the mask length that tells you the first 30 bits of the address is the network. Almost all IPv6 networks will be `/64` because other network sizes will break IPv6 features.

Comment: The proper way to determine if an address is in a network is to perform a bitwise `AND` of the address with the network mask to see if that matches the network address. [This two-part answer`](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) explains how to do that.

Comment: Thanks @RonMaupin, but I think you are over simplifying my problem.  I know how to check if an IP address is in a subnet.  But doing so efficiently with a database indexed by subnet is not trivial. Since Postgres supports IP subnets as a primitive type, and you can check with an SQL query, I was wondering how efficient it is.  Is Postgres doing some magic in the background? Or is it doing naive searching and matching the IP against each subnet?  I don't know and was hoping to get an answer here.

Comment: Then you may want to ask on https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since CIDRs are contiguous, you could add two columns: the minimum and maximum IP addresses in range, and create indexes on those. I wrote a [gist here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=0c6004374c004adece9573f9ac198999) if you want to see the whole thing and play with it.

Basically:

```sql
create table mod_ipdesc
as select addr, category,
  inet(host(network(addr))) as amin,
  inet(host(broadcast(addr))) as amax
from ipdesc;

create index mod_ipdesc_addr on mod_ipdesc(amin, amax);
```

Then:

```sql
select *
from test a
left outer join mod_ipdesc b
on (a.ip between b.amin and b.amax);
```

On your table definition, plus a test table with a few `ip` values (as `inet`), we get:

| ip | addr | category | amin | amax |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 168.192.1.10 | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* |
| 10.10.10.20 | 10.10.10.0/24 | tens | 10.10.10.0 | 10.10.10.255 |
| 50.50.50.1 | 50.50.50.0/24 | fifties | 50.50.50.0 | 50.50.50.255 |
| 50.50.50.1 | 50.50.50.0/30 | sub-fifty | 50.50.50.0 | 50.50.50.3 |
| 50.50.50.10 | 50.50.50.0/24 | fifties | 50.50.50.0 | 50.50.50.255 |

**Update: Query plan comparison**

One thing I couldn't tell initially with such small tables was whether the index was used or not (on the small tables, there was no use of the index, but it could simply be a case where Postgresql determined that a scan was faster). **[YES IT IS]** (for larger tables).

The second question was: is Postgres having some magic that lets it use an index on `inet` column for `<<` type queries? **[NO]** (at least as far as I can tell, using Postgres 9.6).

I created [another gist](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=716314831d8bb707a65212ccc9624ee9) with tables of 1000 entries each.

You can see that the `amin`, `amax` index is used (second plan below), but an index directly on `addr` is not (first plan below: a full table scan):

> ```
> explain
> select * from test a
> left outer join ipdesc b
> on (b.addr >> a.ip);
> ```
>
> ```
> | QUERY PLAN                                                              |
> | :---------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.00..20442.10 rows=6800 width=68)         |
> |   Join Filter: (b.addr >> a.ip)                                         |
> |   ->  Seq Scan on test a  (cost=0.00..23.60 rows=1360 width=32)         |
> |   ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..21.00 rows=1000 width=36)                |
> |         ->  Seq Scan on ipdesc b  (cost=0.00..16.00 rows=1000 width=36) |
> ```

> ```
> explain
> select * from test a
> left outer join mod_ipdesc b
> on (a.ip between b.amin and b.amax);
> ```
>
> ```
> | QUERY PLAN                                                                                   |
> | :------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.28..8001.60 rows=151111 width=132)                            |
> |   ->  Seq Scan on test a  (cost=0.00..23.60 rows=1360 width=32)                              |
> |   ->  Index Scan using mod_ipdesc_addr on mod_ipdesc b  (cost=0.28..4.76 rows=111 width=100) |
> |         Index Cond: ((a.ip >= amin) AND (a.ip <= amax))                                      |
> ```

Comment: So in other words, if I want my query to be efficient, I should expand the subnet to low/high pairs of IPs instead since there isn't any fancy indexing magic that works with the '>>' operator.  Thanks so much for the detailed answer!!

Comment: The "another gist" seems not to be working, the link is dead: Service Unavailable